# Is Google Tango the first/only augmented reality SDK to provide targetless tracking?

Tags: augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I'm trying to learn how to build an augmented reality app to place a 3D object into the world *without* the need for a "target". So far, pretty much every augmented reality framework seems to *only* work with targets; Vuforia, Wikitude, etc. Some have slight extensions on target tracking, such as Vuforia's "Extended Tracking" and "Smart Terrain" features, but in the end these are afflicted by the same limitation -- the SDKs are hopelessly obsessed with "targets".

Then I came across Google Tango. It's hard to tell exactly, but it *appears* to be the only option I could find which offers placing 3D objects into the real world and allowing the user to walk around with the 3D objects staying in place (relative to the world).

Am I correct in my assumption that Google Tango is the only option for this? If I'm going to spend $512 on a Tango development kit, I want to first make sure there weren't other augmented reality libraries I could have used for this.

Comment: do you mean markers? I know you could do markerless tracking AR apps with android using Metaio before in the free version not sure about it anymore thou tbh.

Comment: Yeah, markers, trackers, targets -- that is what I'm referring to. I'll look into metaio.

Answer (score 4):

[Kudan](https://www.kudan.eu/) provides markerless tracking, via SLAM. They have a free trial version and no hardware necessary.

Markerles tracking is not new. 13th Lab's PointCloud SDK prodided markerless tracking a [few years ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQsun1TMBTg). But it removed that offering when their implementation was licensed exclusively by a 3rd party.

The SLAM algorithm is neither new nor proprietary. Anyone can implement it from the CalTech academic paper, though it's a graduate-level problem to tackle!

Comment: BTW, I used the PointCloud SDK years ago and it had pretty good markerless tracking fidelity.

Comment: Does it still exist? The fidelity on Kudan seems to be just okay, not great -- but maybe that's just a problem with how I'm using it, or a limitation of the algorithm.

Comment: No, the PointCloud SDK was licensed exclusively by an anonymous, outside company. It is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://easyar.com markerless tracking and other cool features. And it is free and opensource

Answer (score 1):

[Wikitude](http://www.wikitude.com/wikitude-slam/) also have a markerless tech. I have not tried it to tell how good it works.

Vuforia had something called Smart Terrain which was more of an interaction with environment. But the tech is quite old and I am not sure they kept it going in the last couple of years.

Actually, none can really claim to have a working markerless, it is more of a working in certain conditions. You need proper hardware fast enough to process all the calculations and limited usage conditions as no fast movement and ideal environment.

Microsoft is also coming up with Hololens but hardware is at $3000 and only for dev at the moment.